# How to identify if array is array of object python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I've JSON there I want to identify whether it is an array of an object or just an array of string. How can we identify this in python?

```
arrayA = [{"name", "john", "address": "usa"}, {"name":"adam": "china"}]
arrayB = ["Country", "State"]
```

Comment: Do you know how to check the type of a value? How to access an element from a list?

Comment: Yes. like using isinstance (report_object_in_json, list) ?

Comment: So have you tried that? What happened? Note that when you parse JSON in Python arrays become lists and objects become dictionaries.

Comment: Yeah, I did and it passed. Passed for both arrayA and arrayB

Comment: Then what is your problem?

Comment: After getting instanceof I want to know whether  inside array it is string / object

Comment: Then why don't you check that? Again, do you know how to access an element in a list? Get the element, check its type. What's the *problem*? Give a [mre].

Comment: @Dorian Turba answer I executed and it shows like this. Which also feasible for me
set([<type 'dict'>])
set([<type 'str'>])
set([<type 'dict'>, <type 'str'>])

Comment: Is this for python3 or python2? Select only one tag as the answer will most likely differ between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list comprehension will iterate over the list and create a new list with a boolean for each value. The value of the boolean depend of the type of the element.
Then, `all()` will check if all the elements in the sequence is `True`.

```py
array_a = [{"name": "john", "address": "usa"},
          {"name": "adam", "address": "china"}]
array_b = ["Country", "State"]
array_c = ["Country", "State", {"name": "adam", "address": "china"}]

print(all(isinstance(elem, str) for elem in array_a))
# False
print(all(isinstance(elem, str) for elem in array_b))
# True
print(all(isinstance(elem, str) for elem in array_c))
# False
```

If you don't know this form of statement `[<expression> for <variable> in <iterable>]`, this is how it works: [Data Structures - List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

edit: Thanks B. Morris for your comment ;)

Comment: Haha mybad that's true !